# npm publish (using also lerna) is ignoring ts definition file

Tags: lerna, npm-publish

Hi all I am creating this public library
https://github.com/kristijorgji/winstonjs-utils using ts+lerna monorepo

My issue is that although having specified in every package.json

```
  "files": [
    "./dist"
  ],
```

The file `dist/index.d.ts` is ignored by the publish command

When I build typescript , the dist folder has two files

[image]

But in the published package under dist exists only index.js

I do not have any .npmignore file as you can also see in the public repo I shared.

In all packages packages.json I have specified the typings as well

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "./dist"
  ],
```

Any idea why index.d.ts is excluded from the published packages ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find one solution although might not be the best one.
Nevertheless I am posting in lack of an answer to help everyone facing same issue as me

**Solution:** `I used .npmignore` instead of `files` in package.json
files key seem broken because it ignores index.d.ts files

I used a .npmignore file that excludes unecessary things like

```
__tests__
coverage
src
tasks
.eslintrc.js
jest.config.js
nodemon.debug.json
nodemon.json
tsconfig.json
```

then publishing the package worked great with same result as I intended, having only `dist` folder with index.js index.d.ts inside and package.json and readme.md